# Merge multiple imageviews

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Forgive me If my question is too dumb, I am new to iOS development.

I have 5 imageviews. Each imageview has a different background color.

With a button click I would like to generate 1 image with all the 5 images combined. Meaning (1 image with 5 colors). Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

My storyboard looks similar to the attached image:
[image]

Comment: One image with 5 colors arranged how? You need to give more information about what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: it is not possible to make 1 imageview with 5 color. Please give more information what is your requirement

Comment: @Divine If you want the pictures to be exactly as shown in the image (left to right) you can create an image context 5 times the size of one image and draw each image at its position.

Comment: actually @HAS i want to know what is his requirement. means combine the five color we have to made 1 color ya we have to show that color like a pie chart. so i ask :)

Comment: It is 5 image views with 5 colors. I would like to merge those 5 imageviews into 1.

Comment: Lets say I have 5 imageviews (image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5). I want to combine 5 and make 1 out of it.

Comment: @DivinePropotion So you want them side by side? With margin, without? You need to be exact about your requirements otherwise we can't help you :(

Comment: True that @HAS. Side by side without any margins.

Comment: @DivinePropotion Did you have the time to take a look at my answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method works perfectly for images with the same height, I will add options for images with different heights when I have time for it. (for more information please read the method documentation below).

The method is designed to be class method of `UIImage` which stays in a category.

You can call it like

```
self.generatedImageView.image = [UIImage imageByAppendingImagesSideBySide:@[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]];
```

---

```
/**
 *  Append images side-by-side. This method does not yet support height adjustments (like vertical align), instead images are aligned at the top.
 *  Example:
 *  Pic1 and Pic2 have both the same width and height.
 *  Pic3 has a larger width (which is fully supported).
 *  Pic4 has a larger height (which is **not** supported (yet)). That means that you cannot align the images as you want - they are aligned at the top.
 *  @code
 *  _______________________________________________________________
 *  |           |           |                 |                   |
 *  |           |           |                 |                   |
 *  |   Pic 1   |   Pic 2   |      Pic 3      |                   |
 *  |           |           |                 |                   |
 *  |___________|___________|_________________|        Pic4       |
 *  |                                         |                   |
 *  |                                         |                   |
 *  |                  Empty                  |                   |
 *  |                                         |                   |
 *  |_________________________________________|___________________|
 *
 *  @endcode
 *  @param images An array of UIImages.
 *
 *  @return An image with a width of the sum of all images' widths and a height of the largest image's height.
 */
+ (UIImage *)imageByAppendingImagesSideBySide:(NSArray *)images {
    // Set initial width to zero (we add it step-by-step in the for loop beneath, and height to the first images height, in the for loop we will figure out the image with the largest height.
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(0, ((UIImage *)[images firstObject]).size.height);
    for (UIImage *image in images) {
        if ([image isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            size.width = size.width + image.size.width;
            if (image.size.height > size.height) {
                size.height = image.size.height;
            }
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGPoint currentRightMostPoint = CGPointZero;
    for (UIImage *image in images) {
        if ([image isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            [image drawAtPoint:currentRightMostPoint];
            currentRightMostPoint = CGPointMake(currentRightMostPoint.x + image.size.width, currentRightMostPoint.y);
        }
    }
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: I tried using it as it, but it gave me an error saying no class for method selector. So I tried like the following: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548957/ It gives a warning, method definition not found. Here's the entire project: http://www.tempsend.com/04544732C6. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Change `generatedImageView.image = [ViewController imageByAppendingImagesSideBySide:@[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]];` to `generatedImageView.image = [self imageByAppendingImagesSideBySide:@[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]];` and the `+` before the method name to a `-`. The method was actually intended to stay in a category but you can use it like this anyways ;)

Comment: No errors. Nothing happens when I click the generate button. It is supposed to generate the image and set it as the background image of generatedImageView

Comment: Yeah the problem is that you are passing on an array of `UIImageViews` instead of `UIImages`. Change the array to `image1.image`, etc. (using the variable name `image` for an image view is a bad idea ;))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54758/discussion-between-divine-propotion-and-has).